# Como capturar valor celda de tabla con input text y mostrar en otro input text con Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, jsp

Estimados estoy intentando pasar valores de un input text que está en una tabla html y deseo mostrar ese valor en otro input de otro formulario, pero no he conseguido como hacerlo.
este es el código que uso.Solo me funciona si la celda de la tabla no tiene input text, de lo contrario no funciona ya que al hacer click en la tabla se muestra el código html del input text mas el valor y yo solo quiero capturar el valor del input y mostrarlo en otro input.

```
        <script>
        $( function (){
            $('#tablatest2 tbody tr').click( function(){
                var id2T = $("td:nth-child(2)").text();

                //$('idInput').val();
                //$('#tablatest2').append(newTr);
                $("#nom2").val(id2T);
            });
        });
    </script>


<form>
<table border=1 cellpadding=0 id="tablatest2">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>

<th>NOMBRE</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>

<td><input type="text" value="7845"></td>

<td><input type="text" value="HOLA" id="idInput"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type="text" value="8955"></td>

<td><input type="text" value="HOLAS" id="idInput"></td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

</form>

<br>

<form>

<b>Id:</b><input type="text">

<b>Nombre:</b><input type="text" id="nom2">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, tienes 2 inputs con el mismo id, un id debe ser único para cada elemento html.

Después, veo que en cada  tienes  2  con un input en cada celda, ¿qué input es el que quieres detectar para copiar así valor?

Si fuese el primero :

```
var id2T = $(this).children("td:nth-child(1)").find(input[type=text]).val()
```

Con esto recogerías el valor del primer input que encuentras en la fila.

Y con esto el segundo:

```
var id2T = $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)").find(input[type=text).val()
```

En cualquiera de los casos ya tienes el valor del input que necesitas, puedes asignarlo donde quieras.

Comment: amigo ahora he intentado pero no captura los valores.

Comment: Perdona @SimónPereiraVigouroux , se me olvidó poner $(this) para hacer referencia al elemento del DOM donde haces click, ya lo tienes editado

Comment: ahora si muchas gracias compañero.

Comment: una ultima pregunta , como se puede subir demos para que se puedan probar en esta aplicación?

Comment: Échale un vistazo a este post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: a ok gracias lo revisaré.